# Text to Polylines and Arc Conversion

Tags: c#, windows, truetype

We have a machine that will engrave a given text. The machine will accept only lines and arcs as input. We have a front end application which the user will use to create programs for the machine.

Currently, we have created a geometry file for each letter and number in English. And I think it is not practical to have geometry file if we want to extend this to, say, Japanese or Chinese. So we are trying to build a logic which will convert texts to geometry at runtime.

I am reading about the TTF file format and glyph information. I came across FormattedText and other GlyphRun classes in C#. It is possible to generate outline. But we need a single pixel line. So we are trying to read pixel data and generate lines.

Is there any other simpler better solution to this?

Comment: At first i thought you could look into the internal graphicspath [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathpoints%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I think it uses more than arcs and lines but also other [types of curves](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathtypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

Comment: Not my downvote, but my advice: __Do not care__ when you receive a downvote!!

Comment: How does "we need a single pixel line" work with "the machine will accept only lines and arcs"? A geometric *outline* is not 'a single pixel line' – it's one of the key problems in rasterization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you but here is a piece of code that can help you analyze how fonts are drawn in GDI+. It uses a `GraphicsPath` to draw a string and displays all the control points of the path in different colors..:

[image]

Note how far a few points move out to control the bezier curves of the `Times` glyphs..

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat();
    fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

    using (FontFamily ff = new FontFamily("Times"))
        gp.AddString("CRY", ff, 1, 400, Point.Empty, fmt);
}

 GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();



private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, gp);

    List<Brush> br = new List<Brush>() 
    {Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Green, Brushes.Violet,
     Brushes.DarkKhaki, Brushes.DarkCyan, Brushes.Chocolate};

    int cc = 0;
    if (gp != null && gp.PathPoints != null && gp.PathPoints.Length > 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < gp.PathPoints.Length; i++)
    {
        PointF pt = gp.PathPoints[i];
        int  ptype = gp.PathTypes[i];
        if (ptype != 3) cc = 0; else cc++;
        if (ptype > 3) ptype = 4;
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(br[ptype + cc % 3], pt.X - 3, pt.Y - 3, 6, 6 );
    }
}
```

Check out the details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you think this can help you.

Note though that Fonts are made up from splines or beziers, not arcs.

Comment: Thank you. But this is the output I meant when I mentioned outline. This is a solution but we are more interested in the skeleton. A geometry for the font without width.

Comment: Ah, I understand. That will look rather skewed for many or most fonts. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245003/zhang-suen-thinning-algorithm-c-sharp/26120310?s=1|1.5809#26120310) for an algorithm to achieve that. Input are bitmaps with a resolution of your choice. Output is a bitmap also. You would then have to add a method to trace along the pixels..

Comment: Thanks again. Thats exactly what we are trying to do now. Just wanted to make sure that it is the best of the solutions by asking it here.