# Where is this method declared?

Tags: c#

I was looking for line thinning codes for C#, and the link I found was as below

[Zhang-Suen thinning algorithm C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245003/zhang-suen-thinning-algorithm-c-sharp)

On the last answer there are a series of codes, where part of it was a deep clone function,

```
public static T[][] ArrayClone<T>(T [][] A) 
{ 
     return A.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

Anyone has any idea about what kind class is `A`? Cause when I tried using this code, `A.Select` doesn't work since I never created this class, and the code didn't mention that. Is there any other way to do the line thinning?

Comment: `A` is a double array of the given type `T`. Since arrays are treated as subclasses of `Collection`, they expose the `Select` method. There are plenty of other ways to accomplish this, including a double-nested for-loop to iterate across all elements and copy them into a new array of arrays.

Comment: Did you add `using System.Linq;` with your other `usings`? That is what pulls in the Linq extension methods like `Select()`.

Comment: It is the `bool[][] s` ; see the  `ZhangSuenThinning` header and below!

Comment: Please note that your last question _"Is there any other way to do the line thinning"_ is a completely different question from the main one you seem to have. It's better answered by Google than Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean *specifically* by "doesn't work"? If you are getting the "does not contain a definition … and no extension method … could be found" message, then all you are missing is `using System.Linq;` at the top of the module where you want to use the code.

Note that `A` is not a class at all. It's the name of a *parameter*. IMHO, this is a good example of why people should follow better coding conventions. We are so used to seeing type names in upper-case, when someone writes a variable in upper-case it's hard to recognize it's a variable, even when in theory it should be clear it is just based on its position (a compiler has no trouble with this, but humans have a great deal of trouble with it).

Maybe this version of the method will make clearer what is actually going on:

```
public static T[][] ArrayClone<T>(T [][] array) 
{ 
     return array.Select(subArray => subArray.ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

I.e. you have a generic method named `ArrayClone`. The generic type parameter for this method is `T`. The lone parameter of this method is named `array` (it was `A` in the version you were looking at), and the parameter's type is `T[][]` where `T` is whatever type is the compile-time base array type of the object that is actually passed to the method.

Another way to write the method would be this:

```
public static T[][] ArrayClone<T>(T [][] array) 
{ 
     return System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(
         System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(array,
             subArray => System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(subArray)));
}
```

I.e. without the `using` directive to make the extension method visible, you could just call the static method directly. It's implemented in the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class.