# GraphicsPath font "centerline" of font (for engraving)

Tags: c#, .net, vector, graphicspath

I am writing own custom application for engraver. I can send vector data (lines) to it.

Using [GraphicsPath.AddString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addstring?view=netframework-4.7.2) and retrieving it (using **PathPoints** and **PathTypes**) gives me only outline of the font (lines defining the shape but I need line through the center).

I could do it by hand (like seen [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3997/technique-for-finding-the-centerline-of-a-curved-object)) but it is 26 characters * 2 (upper and lower case) per every font I would want to use.

The **engraver is not self-made** and it is using limited (and modified) version of [HP-GL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-GL) without support for characters.

How can I (by C# code) **calculate** those **lines to engrave**?
Preferably without using external library.

Comment: If you only use the center line how shall you deal with lines of very different widths, like stems vs serifs?

Comment: Actually I believe that tracing the lines by hand based on the path outline is the best solution. Writing a semi-automatic tracer is not so hard and you can always control the quality. Fully automatic typography is not here and may never replace the art of it.. - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245003/zhang-suen-thinning-algorithm-c-sharp/26120310#26120310) is a thinning algorithm but the result tend to be rather ugly. Also: note the GraphicsPath.Flatten method. - The engraver may even need special input, like depth map or layered lines?