# Branch points of the skeleton

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

My code should find the branch points of the skeleton, but the points it finds are not them. Most likely this is because `IMREAD_COLOR` = 1, not 0. But if I set the value to 0, then it stops finding and marking points altogether. Is it because the type of points *(p1, p2, etc)* does not match `Mattype` or something else? How do I fix this?

```
int main() {
    cv::Mat thresh = cv::imread("binary_skeleton.jpg", 1);
    if (thresh.empty())
        return -1;

    for (int i = 1; i < thresh.rows - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < thresh.cols - 1; j++)
        {
            uchar p1 = thresh.at<uchar>(i, j);
            if (0 == p1)
            {
                uchar p1 = thresh.at<uchar>(i, j);
                uchar p2 = thresh.at<uchar>(i - 1, j);
                uchar p3 = thresh.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 1);
                uchar p4 = thresh.at<uchar>(i, j + 1);
                uchar p5 = thresh.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 1);
                uchar p6 = thresh.at<uchar>(i + 1, j);
                uchar p7 = thresh.at<uchar>(i + 1, j - 1);
                uchar p8 = thresh.at<uchar>(i, j - 1);
                uchar p9 = thresh.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 1);

                int same = 0;
                if (p9 == p1) { ++same; }
                if (p8 == p1) { ++same; }
                if (p7 == p1) { ++same; }
                if (p6 == p1) { ++same; }
                if (p5 == p1) { ++same; }
                if (p4 == p1) { ++same; }
                if (p3 == p1) { ++same; }
                if (p2 == p1) { ++same; }

                if (same == 2)
                {
                    circle(thresh, Point(j, i), 3, Scalar(255, 120, 0), 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cv::imshow("", thresh);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

---

[Incorrect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYsje.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you should do with your code:

1. Read the image in using `cv::imread("binary_skeleton.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`. The option you are using forces the image to be RGB, but you are using the image as if if had a single channel.
2. Instead of comparing `if (0 == p1)` to find set pixels, use `if (128 > p1)`. JPEG compression could change the value of pixels, so the image will not have only values of 0 and 255, even if those were the values written to file. Some variation around these values will exist. We simply threshold half-way to ensure that any low value is seen as a skeleton pixel. Likewise, replace `if (p9 == p1)` with `if (128 > p9)`.
3. Branch points always have more than two neighbors set. When two neighbors are set, it’s a point along a line. Instead of `if (same == 2)` use `if (same > 2)`.
4. Remove the second assignment to `p1`, it has no effect.

Comment: If I do exactly as you have written (except that we change the sign in the other direction, since we are interested in black pixels), then I get a strange result. 
[`p1  < 128` and `p9  < 128` _etc_](https://sun9-39.userapi.com/VDOYxKRREGEFtU0EFUB1n30_52aIm26D9WMfRA/Qt4RAh9jrSo.jpg);

If I change to [`p1 > 128` and `p9  < 128` _etc_](https://sun9-72.userapi.com/PacoRZ9-lgrMU9MQI-crK1-FB2FUBFpP9CynKQ/VPBWGqdfPCE.jpg), then I get a lot of marks on the skeleton, but these are still not branch points.

Comment: @avenueroan: if your skeleton is black pixels on a white background, then you need to invert all comparisons, not only the one for p1. But why does your code in the question do `p1==255` if your skeleton has black pixels? // Looking at your result, and the image linked in the question, it seems that you might not have a proper skeleton. How do you compute the skeleton?

Comment: I have inverted all comparisons, yes. // Sorry, I didn't see and forgot to change `p1 == 255` _(changed)_. // Yes, I also thought about the fact that the skeleton may be wrong. I used thresholding => [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26120310/14170471) code written in C # => saved the image => uploaded it here. // Indeed, the only thing I can think of is the skeleton is wrong, since we can apply `cv::threshold(thresh, thresh, 0, 255, cv ::THRESH_BINARY)` to our code to make pixels either 0 or 255, but this is still not will help.

Comment: @avenueroan: The answer you link here shows a result image that is not a correct skeleton. Some points are 8-connected to their neighbors along a line, some are 4-connected (that is, we can remove some pixels without breaking the 8-connected lines). These extra pixels and their neighbors look like branch points. I haven’t looked at the code to see why it’s incorrect. Why don’t you use a standard image processing library? There are many well-tested libraries with correct skeleton algorithms out there.

Comment: I have quite a bit of experience with image processing, so among all the libraries I could find only scikit with the Skeletonize method, but it is only in Python, and I need a C ++ / C # solution. @CrisLuengo

Comment: @avenueroan: The library I know best is DIPlib (I’m an author). It has a very good skeletonization algorithm, [dip::EuclideanSkeleton](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__binary.html#gaf8fe99d5ad2d1be2e2d3d0a0294b8bdb). It’s a C++ library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely try. Maybe this library also contains methods for finding key points? Or some that you know. @CrisLuengo

Comment: @avenueroan: That library has `dip::GetBranchPixels`, which finds the branch pixels in the skeleton. If by "key points" you mean algorithms such as the Harris corner detector, then yes: https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__detection__corners.html

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot. I will write after I try your library. @CrisLuengo