# Finding special points on a fingerprint

Tags: c#, image-processing, fingerprint

I am trying to write a program that finds singular points on a fingerprint.

First, I binarize the picture.

```
private Bitmap binarization(Bitmap sourceBitmap)
        {
            Bitmap targetBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height);
            for (int y = 0; y < sourceBitmap.Height; ++y)
                for (int x = 0; x < sourceBitmap.Width; ++x)
                {
                    Color c = sourceBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                    byte rgb = (byte)(0.3 * c.R + 0.59 * c.G + 0.11 * c.B);
                    targetBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(c.A, rgb, rgb, rgb));
                }
            return targetBitmap;
        }
```

Next, I skeletonize the image (I use the Zhang-Suen algorithm, which I took from [Zhang-Suen thinning algorithm C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245003/zhang-suen-thinning-algorithm-c-sharp))

```
public static bool[][] Image2Bool(Image img)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);
            bool[][] s = new bool[bmp.Height][];
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                s[y] = new bool[bmp.Width];
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                    s[y][x] = bmp.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness() < 0.3;
            }
            return s;

        }

        public static Image Bool2Image(bool[][] s)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s[0].Length, s.Length);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) g.Clear(Color.White);
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                    if (s[y][x]) bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);

            return (Bitmap)bmp;
        }
        public static T[][] ArrayClone<T>(T[][] A)
        { return A.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray(); }

        public static bool[][] ZhangSuenThinning(bool[][] s)
        {
            bool[][] temp = ArrayClone(s); 
            int count = 0;
            do  
            {
                count = step(1, temp, s);
                temp = ArrayClone(s);      
                count += step(2, temp, s);
                temp = ArrayClone(s);      
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return s;
        }

        static int step(int stepNo, bool[][] temp, bool[][] s)
        {
            int count = 0;

            for (int a = 1; a < temp.Length - 1; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 1; b < temp[0].Length - 1; b++)
                {
                    if (SuenThinningAlg(a, b, temp, stepNo == 2))
                    {
                        if (s[a][b]) count++;
                        s[a][b] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        static bool SuenThinningAlg(int x, int y, bool[][] s, bool even)
        {
            bool p2 = s[x][y - 1];
            bool p3 = s[x + 1][y - 1];
            bool p4 = s[x + 1][y];
            bool p5 = s[x + 1][y + 1];
            bool p6 = s[x][y + 1];
            bool p7 = s[x - 1][y + 1];
            bool p8 = s[x - 1][y];
            bool p9 = s[x - 1][y - 1];


            int bp1 = NumberOfNonZeroNeighbors(x, y, s);
            if (bp1 >= 2 && bp1 <= 6) 
            {
                if (NumberOfZeroToOneTransitionFromP9(x, y, s) == 1)
                {
                    if (even)
                    {
                        if (!((p2 && p4) && p8))
                        {
                            if (!((p2 && p6) && p8))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!((p2 && p4) && p6))
                        {
                            if (!((p4 && p6) && p8))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        static int NumberOfZeroToOneTransitionFromP9(int x, int y, bool[][] s)
        {
            bool p2 = s[x][y - 1];
            bool p3 = s[x + 1][y - 1];
            bool p4 = s[x + 1][y];
            bool p5 = s[x + 1][y + 1];
            bool p6 = s[x][y + 1];
            bool p7 = s[x - 1][y + 1];
            bool p8 = s[x - 1][y];
            bool p9 = s[x - 1][y - 1];

            int A = Convert.ToInt32((!p2 && p3)) + Convert.ToInt32((!p3 && p4)) +
                    Convert.ToInt32((!p4 && p5)) + Convert.ToInt32((!p5 && p6)) +
                    Convert.ToInt32((!p6 && p7)) + Convert.ToInt32((!p7 && p8)) +
                    Convert.ToInt32((!p8 && p9)) + Convert.ToInt32((!p9 && p2));
            return A;
        }
        static int NumberOfNonZeroNeighbors(int x, int y, bool[][] s)
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (s[x - 1][y]) count++;
            if (s[x - 1][y + 1]) count++;
            if (s[x - 1][y - 1]) count++;
            if (s[x][y + 1]) count++;
            if (s[x][y - 1]) count++;
            if (s[x + 1][y]) count++;
            if (s[x + 1][y + 1]) count++;
            if (s[x + 1][y - 1]) count++;
            return count;
        }
```

Now I'm trying to highlight the special points. If there is only one black pixel around the point, then this is the end point. (I did it) [endpoints are highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avxhx.jpg)

But I have problems with branch points. They are not highlighted correctly.
[Branching points are marked in purple.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL7vt.png)

If there are 3 black pixels around a point, then this is a branch point. The fact is that the skeletonization algorithm produces the following result: [skeletonized result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb2no.png)

That is, 3 black pixels are counted and gives out as if it were a branch point.

This is the code for finding special points.

```
private int checkThisPoint(Bitmap img, int x, int y)
        {
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++)
                {
                    if (img.GetPixel(i, j) == Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0))
                        c++;
                }
            }
            return c - 1;
        }
private List<List<int>> findCheckPoint(Bitmap img)
        {
            int x = img.Width;
            int y = img.Height;
            List<int> branchPointX = new List<int>();
            List<int> branchPointY = new List<int>();
            List<int> endPointX = new List<int>();
            List<int> endPointY = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    int t;
                    if (img.GetPixel(i, j) == Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0))
                    {
                        t = checkThisPoint(img, i, j);
                        if (t <= 1)
                        {
                            endPointX.Add(i);
                            endPointY.Add(j);
                        }
                        if(t == 3)
                        {
                            branchPointX.Add(i);
                            branchPointY.Add(j);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>();
            a.Add(endPointX);
            a.Add(endPointY);
            a.Add(branchPointX);
            a.Add(branchPointY);
            return a;
        }
```

What do I need to do in order for the branch points to be recognized correctly? Is it worth somehow reworking the skeletonization algorithm, or reworking the search for singular points?